# Android DialogPreference: Cannot resolve method 'registerOnActivityDestroyListener(android.preference.DialogPreference)

Tags: android

I've created a custom preferencedialog that I'm trying to open whenever a switchpreference is set to on.

SettingsFragment:

```
...
@PreferenceChange(R.string.activity_settings_sync_key)
void syncPreferenceChanged(boolean newValue, Preference preference) {
    if (newValue) {
        // Show preferencedialog
        SyncPreference syncpreference = new SyncPreference(getActivity(), null);
        syncpreference.show();

    } else {
        return;
    }
}
...
```

When I run the app and switch on the switchpreference I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void android.preference.PreferenceManager.registerOnActivityDestroyListener(
android.preference.PreferenceManager$OnActivityDestroyListener)'
on a null object reference
    at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:305)
    at com.conhea.smartgfr.preferences.SyncPreference.show(SyncPreference.java:76)
    at com.conhea.smartgfr.preferences.SettingsFragment.syncPreferenceChanged(SettingsFragment.java:53)
    at com.conhea.smartgfr.preferences.SettingsFragment_$1.onPreferenceChange(SettingsFragment_.java:84)
    at android.preference.Preference.callChangeListener(Preference.java:928)
    at android.preference.TwoStatePreference.onClick(TwoStatePreference.java:64)
    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:983)
    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:214)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
    ...
```

When I open the Android DialogPreference class the problem is related to the showDialog method, which cannot resolve the method registerOnActivityDestroyListener():

[image: Picture of DailogPreference$showDialog-method]

It looks as if registerOnActivityDestroyListener doesn't exist in the PreferenceManager class, but I can find it in the [Android sourcecode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceManager.java):

```
/**
 * Registers a listener.
 * 
 * @see OnActivityDestroyListener
 */
void registerOnActivityDestroyListener(OnActivityDestroyListener listener) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mActivityDestroyListeners == null) {
            mActivityDestroyListeners = new ArrayList<OnActivityDestroyListener>();
        }

        if (!mActivityDestroyListeners.contains(listener)) {
            mActivityDestroyListeners.add(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what to do here?

**Update 1**

SyncPreference.java:

```
public class SyncPreference extends DialogPreference {

    private EditText mHostText, mPortText;

    private String mHost;
    private int mPort;
    private final int mDialogLayoutResId = R.layout.dialog_settings_server_preferences;

    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    public SyncPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setPersistent(false);
        setDialogLayoutResource(mDialogLayoutResId);
        setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
        setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);
    }

    @Override
    public int getDialogLayoutResource() {
        return mDialogLayoutResId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);

        mHostText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_settings_server_host_ip);
        mPortText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_settings_server_port);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue,
                                     Object defaultValue) {

        // Restore existing state
        mHostText.setText(getHost());
        mPortText.setText(String.valueOf(getPort()));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            setHost(mHostText.getText().toString());
            setPort(Integer.valueOf(mPortText.getText().toString()));
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        showDialog(null);
    }

    private String getHost() {
        return getSharedPreferences().getString(
                getContext().getString(R.string.activity_settings_server_host_ip_key),
                getContext()
                        .getString(R.string.activity_settings_server_host_ip_default));
    }

    private int getPort() {
        return getSharedPreferences().getInt(
                getContext().getString(R.string.activity_settings_server_port_key),
                Integer.valueOf(getContext()
                        .getString(R.string.activity_settings_server_port_default)));
    }

    private void setHost(String host) {
        this.mHost = host;

        getSharedPreferences().edit().putString(
                getContext().getString(R.string.activity_settings_server_host_ip_key),
                host).apply();
    }

    private void setPort(int port) {
        this.mPort = port;

        getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt(
                getContext().getString(R.string.activity_settings_server_port_key),
                port).apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post SyncPreference.show() method?

Comment: Added my synpreference class.